# TypeError: Cannot read property 'languages' of undefined in react-localize-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I was trying to implement react-localize-redux to my application. But I got following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'languages' of undefined

This coming from *node_modules/react-localize-redux/es/localize.js:249*

My code implementation as follow.

```
let store = createStore(combineReducers({icm: icmReducer, locale: locale}));

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <LocalizeProvider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </LocalizeProvider>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.initialize({
        languages: [
            {name: "English", code: "en"},
            {name: "French", code: "fr"}
        ],
        translation: globalTranslations,
        options: {renderToStaticMarkup}
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="App container">
            <Header/>
            <InvoiceAudit/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withLocalize(App);
```

global.json

```
{
 "welcome": {
"greeting": [
  "Hello",
  "Bonjour",
  "Hola"
],
"farewell": [
  "Goodbye",
  "Au revoir",
  "Adiós"
  ]
 }
}
```

**Error**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. When we are using combine reducers with localizeReducer then we need to provide the name as **localize**. it is must otherwise it won't work.

```
import {LocalizeProvider, localizeReducer} from 'react-localize-redux';
```

`let store = createStore(combineReducers({icm: IcmWebReducer, localize: localizeReducer}));`

This is mentioned in here: https://ryandrewjohnson.github.io/react-localize-redux-docs/#what-if-i-want-to-use-redux

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have 2 languages initialized, but 3 translations. You should add spanish to your initializer:

```
languages: [
  {name: "English", code: "en"},
  {name: "French", code: "fr"},
  {name: "Spanish", code: "es"}
],
```

(just guessing this is the problem)

Comment: This didn't help. Can react-localize-redux be used in react.js application.?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `localize` with different name or in different path in your store just use `getState` property.

(TypeScript)

```
<LocalizeProvider
  store={store}
  getState={(state: AppState) => state.user.locale}
>
//...
</LocalizeProvider>
```

The result of the app state: [state.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpddz.png)